# adding the quantity of same book title

Tags: reference

this is the code that i construct,
please help me to fix my code.

```
$table="<tr>
   <td>Book Title</td>
       <td>Quantity</td>
     </tr>";
$query = "select * from book";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   $table.="<tr>
             <td>{$row['title']}</td>
             <td>{$row['quantity']}</td>
            </tr>";
}
$table="<table border>$table</table>";
echo $table;
```

Comment: What is your question, Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql is deprecated, but that's another topic.

You are able to fetch count of books with same title in your query:

```
$table="<tr>
       <td>Book Title</td>
       <td>Quantity</td>
     </tr>";
$query = "SELECT b.title, (SELECT COUNT(bc.title FROM book AS bc WHERE b.title=bc.title) AS quantity FROM book AS b";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   $table.="<tr>
             <td>{$row['title']}</td>
             <td>{$row['quantity']}</td>
            </tr>";
}
$table="<table border>$table</table>";
echo $table;
```